In Jupyter/VSCode running conda envs, how do I make it run activation scripts in activate.d?
Conda or Mamba provides a way to set shell environment variables upon activating the environment -- .sh scripts stored in /path/to/env/etc/conda/activate.d/ or .../deactivate.d/ run upon activating and deactivating the environment. This is utilized by many packages to link their programs and libraries, should it be necessary.
It seems neither Jupyter kernel nor VScode extensions are not aware of these scripts and do not run them upon activation. In my case, this makes some of the paths broken, making it impossible to import some packages unless I maunally add them to path via sys.
EDIT: Just checked: manually adding sys does not make help importing the library. The library itself should load *.so objects and so on, which also relies on environment variables.
How do I make either of them (preferably both) aware of activation scrips and run them upon starting up kernel?
